# Terminate the win32 process of UWP app from main UWP process, or send message to it

Tags: c#, desktop-bridge

I'm creating a UWP application which has a main part which runs on all devices, and also a win32 process which adds some extra features to the app, and runs when the app is running on PCs. (As described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-extensions#win32-process))

Now, this win32 part is optional, and I want users to be able to enable or disable it. So when user enables it, I can run the win32 process (which is located in the same package). But when user disables it, how can I terminate the win32 process?

Somehow I need to send a message to the app asking it to terminate, or killing it. Is there any way to achieve this?

*I've looked into [app services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/app-services), but it seems it's only possible to initiate conversation from the Desktop app to UWP app, not the other way round.*

Comment: Then why not initiate conversation from the desktop asking if it needs to kill itself?

Comment: @DavidG The enable/disable toggle is in the settings page, which is in the modern UWP part. So, how desktop app is supposed to know when to initiate conversation with the modern UWP part? Polling every few seconds is possible, but is far from ideal.

Comment: My doubt is that the security model of UWP won't let you initiate a connection to your app, though perhaps you could do it with sockets?

Comment: @DavidG I think such connection to `localhost` is not allowed in UWP.

Comment: Then initiate the connection from the desktop app

Comment: @DavidG it seems that it's blocked both ways, meaning the UWP neither can receive requests from another process in the same machine nor send requests to a listener on a different process located on the same machine.

Comment: What about the app services thing you linked?

Comment: @DavidG with app services, I would have to create a connection and send a message from desktop app, then avoid responding immediately in UWP. While that could work, it's feels like a hack. I'm looking to see if a better option exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the Win32 process launches, establish an app service connection to the UWP. Now you can tie the lifetime of the Win32 process to the app service connection (by listening to the ServiceClosed event). This way the Win32 process will go away when the UWP process closes, or when UWP app decides to close the app service connection.

Here is a sample that uses that technique:
https://github.com/Microsoft/DesktopBridgeToUWP-Samples/tree/master/Samples/UWP%20Office%20Interop